# Bad Request is returned when Amplify is configured for hosted UI in Angular 6

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Was going through the documentation of Amplify, to configure AWS Cognito hosted UI in Angular 6.
Getting 400 Bad request after login.

Below is the info:

1. In **main.ts** AWS Amplify was configured.

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXXX',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
    oauth: {
      domain: 'IDP.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
      scope: ['openid'],
      redirectSignIn:  'http://localhost:4200/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      responseType: 'code', 
      options: {
        AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

2. In the **app-component.ts**:

```js
 import { Auth} from 'aws-amplify';

 onLoginClick() {
    Auth.federatedSignIn();
 }
```

3. **Chrome console** logs.

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

4. Network Tab.

[image: Network Tab]

Comment: There is an open issue associated with version 1.1.29 : https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

1. We need to create User Pool without generating client_secret.

[image: User Pool]

2. Updated package.json

```
    "aws-amplify": "1.1.28",
    "@aws-amplify/ui": "1.0.19",
```

3. Disabled analytics:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXXX',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'client_id',
    oauth: {
      domain: 'idp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
      scope: ['openid'],
      redirectSignIn:  'http://localhost:4200/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      responseType: 'code',
      options: {
        AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true
      }
    }
  },
  Analytics:{
    disabled:true
  }
});
```

Output:
[image: Output]